# ListView Context Menu

Tags: java, android

I am working with ContextMenu on my ListView. The problem I'm facing is I'm not getting ContextMenu on item that is already selected in ListView since it is not touchable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!
What I did is `"android:focusable="false"` for all the buttons inside my ListView item, they were stealing the focus making selected list item non-touchable.
Reference: [click-events-listview-gridview](http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/)

Answer (score 0):

call this inside  `onCreate():`

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

And to access the selected item during long click:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.lv) {
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    YourObject obj = (YourObject) lv.getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);

    menu.add("One");
    menu.add("Two");
    menu.add("Three");
    menu.add(obj.name);
}
}
```

Comment: I've already done that, I'm getting ContextMenu but problem is, let's say I've following items int List:
Cheese A
Cheese B
Cheese C
When Cheese A is clicked, I get ContextMenu on long pressing B and C, but don't get when Cheese A is long pressed.

Comment: `listViewConversations = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewConversationList);
  conversationListAdaptor = new ConversationListAdaptor(getActivity());
  listViewConversations.setAdapter(conversationListAdaptor);
  listViewConversations.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
  listViewConversations.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  registerForContextMenu(listViewConversations);`
It's a custom adaptor.